# Rolling median of deviation from the current value

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a dataframe in pandas indexed by timestamps. For each point I need to compute median of absolute differences between the future values in the next 5 seconds and the current one. For example,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 1, 3, 4, -1, 2, -3, 5, 4, -10]},
    index=pd.date_range('2022-01-01', periods=10, freq='s'))
```

In the output the first entry will have index `2022-01-01 00:00:00` and the value of `1`. How was this `1` computed? For the next 5 seconds we have values `2,1,3,4,-1,2`, the absolute differences with the first element are hence `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 0`, which gives a median of `1`.

If that's gonna be simpler, I'm also happy to know the answer in case the window is backward-looking. It seems that using forward-looking windows is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @Corralien the question was about the median, so it would be `2` I think

Answer (score 2):

Use `rolling_apply`:

```
compute_function = lambda x: np.median(np.abs(x - x[0]))
out = df['A'].rolling('6S').apply(compute_function).shift(-5)
print(out)

# Output
2022-01-01 00:00:00    1.0
2022-01-01 00:00:01    2.0
2022-01-01 00:00:02    1.5
2022-01-01 00:00:03    1.5
2022-01-01 00:00:04    4.0
2022-01-01 00:00:05    NaN
2022-01-01 00:00:06    NaN
2022-01-01 00:00:07    NaN
2022-01-01 00:00:08    NaN
2022-01-01 00:00:09    NaN
Freq: S, Name: A, dtype: float64
```

This works because you have no hole in your timeseries (cause `shift`)

**Update** Solution from @ilya (author)

```
compute_function = lambda x: (x - x[-1]).abs().median()
out = df[::-1].rolling('5S')['A'].apply(compute_function)[::-1]
print(out)

# Output
2022-01-01 00:00:00    1.0
2022-01-01 00:00:01    2.0
2022-01-01 00:00:02    1.0
2022-01-01 00:00:03    2.0
2022-01-01 00:00:04    3.0
2022-01-01 00:00:05    3.0
2022-01-01 00:00:06    7.0
2022-01-01 00:00:07    1.0
2022-01-01 00:00:08    7.0
2022-01-01 00:00:09    0.0
Freq: S, Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: i think it should be 6S and it should be x - x[0] not diff and with raw=True and numpy operations

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you explain a bit how does this work? In my understanding, `.rolling('5S')` will provide backward-looking window. Also, you do apply `lambda` to the roll row? Will it compute absolute differences between its consecutive members?

Comment: @Ilya. Do you have some missing timestamp?

Comment: @Corralien well, time gaps are not uniform if that's what you mean. So I guess shifting won't be an option

Comment: Does `reindex` dataframe and fill hole with nan is an option?

Comment: no, it will blow it up. What do you think about the following? `df.A.[::-1].rolling('5S').apply(lambda x : (x - x[-1]).abs().median())[::-1]` It seems to work well in my case

Comment: Yes it works well. I just got it the backward-looking :-)

Comment: However why not '6S'? The current time and 5 other seconds

Comment: the time resolution may be lower than a second, right?

Comment: Yes, check this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) (bottom of table)